# May a ref class be stored by value in a managed class?

Tags: c++-cli

Say I have a managed type `Foo`:

```
ref class Foo
{};
```

And a managed type `Bar`:

```
ref class Bar
{
   Foo foo;
};
```

Note that `Bar` does not contain a `Foo^`, but a `Foo`.

Assume that `Bar` is `gcnew`'d.

Is this permitted?

It compiles without warning, yet [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-consume-classes-and-structs-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019) says:

> Reference (ref) types can only be instantiated on the managed heap, not on the stack or on the native heap. Value types can be instantiated on the stack or the managed heap.

I suppose it's transitively "on the managed heap", but I'd like confirmation.

<sub>Reason I ask is that I'm possibly seeing some evidence that my `foo` is corrupt when I later access it; MCVE perhaps to follow in a subsequent question, depending on the outcome of this one!</sub>

Comment: Ecma-372, section 19.11 ("Note: This includes handle types").  Automatically initialized by the constructor with a gcnew expression.

Comment: Ooh I didn't realise the language were publicly specified

Comment: Hmm this isn't a literal though and the question's about _not_ using handle types?

Comment: thanks Hans that set me on the right path I think

Answer (score 2):

**It seems to be valid.**

The language is specified by [ECMA-372](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf), which does not appear to prevent this (though I cannot immediately find any explicitly stated semantics for it, either).

In particular, §23 (p141) lists restrictions on "mixed types":

> This clause is reserved for possible future use.
>
> A mixed type is a native class, ref class, or native array that requires object members, either by declaration or by inheritance, to be allocated on both the CLI heap and some other part of memory.
>
> Examples of mixed types are:
>
> - A native class containing a member whose type is a non-simple value type, a ref class type, or interface class type.
> - A native array of elements whose type is a value type other than a fundamental type, or a ref class type.
> - A ref class or value class containing a member whose type is a native class or native array.
>
> A program that defines or declares a mixed type is ill-formed.

…and your example is not one of them. I'd expect to find it listed there if it were prohibited.

<sup>(not sure what's going on with that first paragraph)</sup>

Comment: also I found the bug and it wasn't there :P

Comment: Using "your" to refer to yourself, +1 grammar vote.